# Amazon s3 bucket policy access denied when hosting static webpage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, web-deployment

I have been trying to host a simple static webpage on s3. However, when I was clicking on the endpoint through the properties --> static website hosting section, the screen displayed a 403 error with the message: AccessDenied.

I later tried to make the bucket content public by changing the bucket policy's principal part to "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            }, but the same error message AccessDenied popped up again.

Is there any way I can grant public access to view my webpage by getting the permission to change the bucket policy of my own bucket created by my own account, I tried to follow the official tutorial for hosting static website on s3 but I am denied of access while the tutorial does not have this issue at all.

Comment: Verify that you didn't previously configure your bucket to block public access.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the tutorial you used? It might be out-of-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try changing your : "Principal": { "AWS": "*" }
to "Principal": "*"

Can you please also share the whole policy you are using.

Please refer the following url:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html